# Как изменить цвет compound button в appcompat-v7

Tags: android, checkbox

Допустим создаю стандартный :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
    android:text="Save to file ?"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="?attr/listPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,RtlSymmetry"
    android:checked="true"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    style="@style/cbutton"
    android:theme="@style/cbutton" />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Либо через styles для этого элемента, либо создать Drawable в коде.

```
<style name="cbutton">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/blue_400</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/red_400</item>
</style>
```

Через код

```
import android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper;

final AppCompatCheckedTextView view = (AppCompatCheckedTextView) findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
final int[] attrs = {android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple};
final ContextThemeWrapper contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme);
final TypedArray a = contextThemeWrapper.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
Drawable indicator = null;
try {
    final int resourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    indicator = ContextCompat.getDrawable(contextThemeWrapper, resourceId);
} finally {
    a.recycle();
}

if (indicator != null) {
    indicator = indicator.mutate();

    final int[][] states = new int[3][];
    final int[] colors = new int[3];
    states[0] = new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled};
    colors[0] = getResources().getColor(R.color.green_600);

    states[1] = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked};
    colors[1] = getResources().getColor(R.color.red_400);

    states[2] = new int[0];
    colors[2] = getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_400);

    final ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

    indicator = DrawableCompat.wrap(indicator);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(indicator, colorStateList);
    view.setCheckMarkDrawable(indicator);
}
```

Comment: через styles - это для `style="@style/cbutton"` или для `android:theme="@style/cbutton" />` ?

Comment: @Andreyua, через android:theme="@style/cbutton"

Comment: Ещё вопрос, а как тогда изменять эту тему динамически, соответственно изменению основной темы (напр основная тема лайт - цвет чекбокса один, тема дарк - цвет чекбокса - другой ? Со ` style="@style/cbutton" ` я знаю как, а с ` android:theme` - не уверен ...

Comment: У меня style="@style/cbutton не влияет на цвет, только android:theme="@style/cbutton" помогает

Comment: ну да, так и есть...  поэтому и задавал вопрос

Comment: @Andreyua, после изменения theme необходимо пересоздать все view.

Answer (score 0):

Вот нужное поле. Поменять на свое и будет работать.

```
android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```